# Select2.js two select box appear

Tags: select, jquery-select2, bootstrap-4, box

I'm trying to implement select2.js in my project, but, when using an example from their page, two select boxes appear. I'm using bootstrap and the last version of select2.

```
@section Scripts{
  @Scripts.Render("~/plugins/select2")
}

@section Styles{
  @Styles.Render("~/plugins/select2Styles")
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    //$("#selectStoreId").select2();
    $(".select2_demo_1").select2({
        placeholder: 'Select an option',
        dropdownParent: $(".select2_demo_1")
    });
});
</script>

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4">
     <p>
         Select2 is a jQuery based replacement for select boxes. It can take 
       a regular select box and turn it into:
    </p>
    <select class="select2_demo_1 form-control">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4">Option 4</option>
        <option value="5">Option 5</option>
      </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I obtain: 
[Two select boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoytL.png)

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Please help:)

Comment: Try to remove the form-control class from the select tag. To me, it worked.

Comment: Did you solved it? I have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I was not importing the correct css file structure.

Answer (score 0):

I added "select2-hidden-accessible" in the form class and it worked for me or you can add it in jquery to explicitly add the class to the select element.

```
$("select").addClass("select2-hidden-accessible");
```